# Get different values and similar values on two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

Here I am trying to find the same values and different values from two different `arrays` that fetch from the `MYSQL` database. Following is the code that I tried to accomplish but I can't see any results including no errors. The `testing_details` indicates the `JSON` value that I fetch from `database`.

Here is the codes:

```
<?php
  include ('auth/dbconnection.php');

   $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM testing_schedule AS t INNER JOIN  prescription AS p ON  
   t.p_id=p.p_id AND p.date=curdate() AND p.apt_id=? ");
   $stmt2->bind_param("s", $_GET['aptid']);
   $stmt2->execute();
   $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
   if($result2->num_rows === 0)  ;
   while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    $testing_perform= $row['testing_perform'];
    $found = false;

$testing_details = json_decode($row['testing_details'],true);

    if (is_array($testing_details) || is_object($testing_details)) {
        if (is_array($testing_perform) || is_object($testing_perform)) {

        foreach($testing_details as $key => $object) {
            $found = false;

            foreach ($testing_perform as $keys => $object2) {
                if ($object == $object2) {
      
 ?>

                <tr>
                   <td>2</td>
                   <td><a href="invoice-view.php">#INV-0002</a></td>
                   <td><?php    echo '<br>'. $object2 .': check ';     
                    $found = true; ?>  </td>
                    <td>24 Aug 2018</td>
                    <td>24 Aug 2018</td>
                    <td>$6</td>
                    <td><span class="custom-badge status-blue">Sent</span></td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                     </td>
              </tr>
                                
   <?php  }} }  } } } ?>
```

Below is the picture which indicates the two arrays that how they stored in database `(DB schema)`...

**testing_perform:**

[image: testing perporm]

**testing_details:**

[image: testing_details]

Comment: This code seems to be writing to the middle of a table, right? Did the code / output (supposedly the `</table>` close tag, at least) after this got print to the HTML source code?

Comment: @KoalaYeung Here I want to show `$object2` in the middle of the `table`  as a  `td`.

Comment: What I wanted to know is if there is any runtime error with your code. I know you saw no error message, but server can be configed to show no error message at all. The PHP shown is clearly not the full version of your code. I was asking if there is any output after the loop? Or is there any output on your page at all?

Comment: No. there are no any result seen.

Comment: If the server did give you any HTML on the page, that means it has to be an error. Do you have access to any server log?

Comment: No, other rows are viewd successfully throygh `echo` statement, but this is not viewed.